# Manipulating and moving text in a scene

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have a scene where upon entering text into a text field, a javaFX Text object gets populated with text from the input field.

here is the code -

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class TextEntry extends Application
{
    private static Text textFX;
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        Pane root = new Pane();

        TextField enterText = new TextField();
        enterText.setFont(Font.font("SanSerif",20));

        enterText.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldTextValue, newTextValue) ->
        {           
            textFX = new Text(150,300,newTextValue);
            Font Sanserif = Font.font("Phosphate",50);
            textFX.setFont(Sanserif);
            textFX.setFill(Color.BLUE);
            root.getChildren().add(textFX);
        });

        root.setOnMouseMoved(e ->{
            if(textFX.contains(e.getX(),e.getY()))
                textFX.setOnMouseDragged(f ->{
                    textFX.setX(f.getX());
                    textFX.setY(f.getY());
                });     
        });


        root.getChildren().add(enterText);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,600,600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Text Entry");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

A few problems -

1. The listener responds to text being entered, but not deleted. Does it have anything to do with the various listener types - invalidation listener, and/or remove listener? I am new to JavaFX (Just relatively new to Java!) and don't fully understand them.
2. Multiple text objects get created every time a new letter is inputed into the text field. I only want to create ONE new object and edit it, i realise it's because I am asking for a new text object to be created every time the value is updated, but can't think of a way around this?

NOTE: eventually I want to be able to create multiple text objects, in different fonts and sizes.

3. As a product of problem number 2. the text item can be moved around the scene (great!), but only the most recent one created (not so great). I'm not sure what is wrong with my code where this is supposed to happen?

Any assistance on these problems would be Massively appreciated!

Comment: Why is `textFX` static?

Comment: Static is a class variable right? As in by declaring a variable as static, it can't be used in another class?.. haha, I wasn't really thinking to be honest!

Comment: That's not what `static` (or "class variable") means at all.

Comment: Thats my understanding of it in the bin then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create the `Text` object and add it to the screen once, and then update it's text in the listener.

Also, there is no need to reset the drag listener every time the mouse moves. You only need to register it once.

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage)
{
    Pane root = new Pane();

    TextField enterText = new TextField();
    enterText.setFont(Font.font("SanSerif",20));

    textFX = new Text(150,300,"");
    Font Sanserif = Font.font("Phosphate",50);
    textFX.setFont(Sanserif);
    textFX.setFill(Color.BLUE);
    root.getChildren().add(textFX);


    textFX.setOnMouseDragged(e ->{
        textFX.setX(e.getX());
        textFX.setY(e.getY());
    });     


    root.getChildren().add(enterText);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root,600,600);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Text Entry");
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

At this point, instead of the listener, you can just use a binding:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage)
{
    Pane root = new Pane();

    TextField enterText = new TextField();
    enterText.setFont(Font.font("SanSerif",20));

    textFX = new Text(150,300,"");
    Font Sanserif = Font.font("Phosphate",50);
    textFX.setFont(Sanserif);
    textFX.setFill(Color.BLUE);
    root.getChildren().add(textFX);


    textFX.textProperty().bind(enterText.textProperty());

    textFX.setOnMouseDragged(e ->{
        textFX.setX(e.getX());
        textFX.setY(e.getY());
    });     


    root.getChildren().add(enterText);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root,600,600);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Text Entry");
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: saves the day again. Thanks for your help earlier too! I may be posting more questions (update the same question?) based on this program, but not until I've tried absolutely everything I can to achieve what i want. Thanks again